# What are my options for migrating data from Cassandra split into files by name?

Tags: java, cassandra, data-migration

I have table with following structure

id| received_date | data
1 | 13.12.2020    | alex : 1
2 | 14.12.2020    | alex : 2
3 | 14.12.2020    | vova : 999
4 | 15.12.2020    | vova : 888

I split field "data" into two fields "name" and "number"

alex = [1,2,3,4,5, ....]
vova = [999,888,777,666,555, ....]

What is the best solution for group data by name and migrate to files by name.
One name may contains 6 million records. These names could be more than 3000. So I should migrate 3000 * 6 millions records (more than 18 billion). So after migration I should have files containing alex and vova (alex.bin, vova.bin)
After migration to the file, I should download the file to google cloud storage

Comment: Since the data is not present as the primary key I think you will have to do the full table read. You will get better answers if you can clarify what are your concerns in just reading data from Cassandra and create files using java program.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg, if I group data in memory using HashMap for example, so my memory will run out of room on my application.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an analytics operation so your best option is to write a Spark application to do the ETL and write the data to disk. Cheers!